# Self-respecting person + How to ask someone to maintain their self-respect?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request, sentence-structure

How to tell someone to observe their self-respect in the manner that they could show they value themselves?
The only way we say in Farsi is:

> - Maintain your self-respect.

Does the above sentence make any sense to you? Can it be considered a natural sentence in English.

Meanwhile, I would appreciate it if you could let me know what would you call such a person who respects themselves?
the only choice which comes to mind is "**self-respecting person**"

Comment: Are you thinking of an equivalent to خـَليك مـُحتـَر َم? If so, it probably relates to concepts that don't really exist outside the arab world. The nearest equivalent would be **behave yourself**!

Comment: @JavaLatte it's Arabic language while I'm a Persian. :) Though I know some other languages and the word you've defined is not at all what I am looking for. With "behave yourself" I'm sure you didn't get me right. ;)

Comment: There are lots of articles about diference of self-esteem and self-respect. I know the term I'm looking for is "self-respect" which is not involved in pride and is a way for growing confidence. This is another very formal term in even political science and when it comes to international relationships not only when we're talking about relations between two individuals.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain your self-respect.

The sentence is grammatical.  However, the use of "keep" is a bit more common.

It's difficult to keep your self-respect when you have been unemployed for a long time. (Longman).

Comment: As a native speaker of U.S. English, I like the sentence, "Maintain your self-respect." _Maintain_ seems a completely natural choice of word in this context, _keep_ slightly less so. But some other English speakers apparently disagree, if Google ngrams is to be believed.

Comment: @DavidK,  Being a native speaker, you  know which is better.  BTW, I myself will go for maintain.